# Android Auto - Communication between background service and Activity

Tags: java, android, android-auto, mediabrowserservice

I'm attempting to add a `MediaBrowserService` for Android Auto to an existing media-player app.  The app has a single activity which manages the `MediaSession`, `Callbacks` and related state.  It has been set up so that it emits events, which the background `MediaBrowserService` consumes and uses to build its content tree.

This all works fine when the flow is like:

`Start my app -> Start Android Auto -> Browse media`

However, it falls flat on its face when the flow is:

`Start Android Auto -> Browse media`

...as in, when the app is not started and running in the background prior to when Android Auto is launched.

The problem appears to be that although my `MediaBrowserService` will be automatically launched by Android Auto, it does not create a corresponding instance of my app's `Activity` when it does so (which means no events to inform the `MediaBrowserService`, and consequently no content available in Android Auto).

Ideally it seems like the `MediaBrowserService` needs to be able to check and see if the app's "main" `Activity` is running, and spawn a new instance if/when it is not.  But not sure if that's possible, and it tends to feel like it's the wrong approach to take here.

What's the correct way to work around this issue?  I don't want to replicate all of the app's `MediaSession` handling and playback-related code in the `MediaBrowserService` implementation.  That should be kept as lightweight as possible.  Is there a way to ensure that the app's `Activity` is always running whenever the `MediaBrowserService` is active?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this was refactoring.  Lots and lots of refactoring.

In a nutshell, Android expects Activities to be used to fill a [particular architectural niche](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities.html#tcoa).  Specifically, the niche where you're displaying an interface to the user via the device's screen.  Other use-cases, such as having a 'headless' `Activity` running in the background, appear to be neither expected nor supported.

Thus the answer was to take all of the app's playback-related code out of the `Activity`, move it into a background `Service`, and provide an API for passing on the relevant commands (and receiving data, state updates and so on) either from/to the foreground `Activity` (if/when the user is interacting with the app's UI) or from/to the `MediaBrowserService` (if/when the user is interacting through Android Auto's UI).  Starting the service is something that can be easily done from either context, if/when needed.

That appears to be the solution.  It certainly can be tedious if you've got a nontrivial existing codebase you're working with.  Far better to anticipate this sort of issue, and architect your app accordingly from the start; keep things that aren't directly pertinent to your app's UI outside of your `Activity` implementation(s).